# An $R_P$ that's a field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals, localization

Let $R=\mathbb{C}[x]$ and $P=\{f(x)\in R|f(0)=0\}$. Then is $R_P$ a field?

I think so... my reasoning:

There's a bijective correspondence between prime ideals in $R_P$ and those in $R$ not intersecting $R\setminus P$ (Eisenbud Prop 2.2b). $R$ is a PID so every prime ideal is maximal. That is, prime ideals are of the form $(f(x))$ for some irreducible $f(x)\in R$. But $R\setminus P$ is the set of all functions with nonzero constant coefficient ($f(0)\neq 0$). Hence, if $(f(x))\cap (R\setminus P)=\emptyset$, then in particular $f(x)$ must have been in $R\setminus P$. But then $x|f(x)$ so $f(x)$ isn't irreducible. Therefore, there is no nonzero prime ideal that doesn't interset $R\setminus P$.

Hence, under the bijective correspondence, there are no nontrivial prime ideals in $R_P$. But since every nontrivial ideal can be extended to a maximal (prime) ideal, this implies that $R_P$ only has trivial ideals, i.e., $R_P$ is a field.

Comment: would you not be able to show that P satisfies the field axioms?

Comment: I don't think I understand your question. Are you saying that $R_P$ is a field?

Comment: What is $R_P$? $\ $

Comment: Where this goes wrong is in your conclusion that $x$ divides $f$. $x$ precisely divides those polynomials in $P$, not in its complement.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft $f$ is the generator of $P$ - so $f(x) = x$. In fact, that's where the proof goes wrong: "$x|f$, so $f$ is not irreducible". Not so, $f$ could just be equal to $x$. And it is.

Comment: @JackM Ahh, I was not thinking this through. So his mistake is where you said, and he also has an error in the conclusion that $f$ is in $R\setminus P$ since the conclusion is precisely that it is in $P$.

Comment: I think this is very relevant: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/150892/when-the-localization-of-a-ring-is-a-field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But then $x|f(x)$ so $f(x)$ isn't irreducible

This step is incorrect.  If $x$ is a *proper* factor of $f(x)$ (that is, $x\mid f(x)$ and $f(x)/x$ is not a unit), then this would mean $f(x)$ is not irreducible.  But $f(x)$ might be a unit times $x$.  In fact, in that case $f(x)$ *is* irreducible, and $(f(x))=P$.  So there is exactly one nonzero prime ideal in $R$ that does not intersect $R\setminus P$, namely $P$ itself.  As a result, the localization $R_P$ has one nonzero prime ideal and is not a field.

Answer (score 4):

In a PID every ***nonzero*** prime ideal is maximal. But the zero ideal is prime, because the ring is a domain.

Since $P$ is a prime ideal (easy proof), there is a bijection between the prime ideals in $R_P$ and the prime ideals of $R$ contained in $P$. So $R_P$ has ***two*** prime ideals, hence it's not a field.

---

If $R$ is a domain, the only prime ideal $P$ such that $R_P$ is a field, is $P=\{0\}$. Indeed, the same argument as before applies: a nonzero prime ideal contains at least two prime ideals, itself and $\{0\}$.